# react-router: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm struggling with react router.
all i want is to build a side menu with a link to login that will show the Login comp in the right pane.
so this is the HTML:

```
<main id="buschat-app"></main>
<div id="menu"></div>
```

This is how i render the Buschat main comp and the Router comp.

```
   class Buschat extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-2">
                        <Menu />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-10">
                        <Main />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Buschat />, document.getElementById('buschat-app'))
ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Default}/>
        <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('menu'));
```

now, in i have the Menu comp that looks like that:

```
 import React from 'react';
import { Link  } from 'react-router'

export default class Menu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
                        <Link to="/">Default</Link>
                        <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                </nav>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

when the page is load i see the 2 links on the right.
when i click on the login link, i get this console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

what im doing wrong? how react-router knows to render login comp on the right pane?
sorry but im new to this...

Comment: `<Router history={hashHistory}>` looks strange to me. Are you renaming the `browserHistory` import that should be used with the latest version of React router?

Comment: no, i took it from this example:
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/02-rendering-a-route

they say to import like this:
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router'

Comment: Your Buschat, and therefore your Menu components are not inside the same application as your react-router component. You can only use `Link` in the same app where you have your Router. 99% of React applications only call `ReactDOM.render` one time creating one React app.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing context reference in React Component.

```
 static contextTypes = {router: PropTypes.object.isRequired};
```

Ref: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3024

Answer (score 0):

Remove

`ReactDOM.render(<Buschat />, document.getElementById('buschat-app'))`

and change to

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Buschat}/>
        <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('buschat-app'));
```

in `Buschat` class, add the `<Menu>` component.

I hope this helps!